Looking for assistance in expect
I have a bash script that has expect to login to a remote host and run list of commands. It works as expected. It has a flaw, if the user enters the wrong password, the expect script keeps trying the password for multiple times. Some host on network are now updated to block the newer ssh connection if there was multiple ssh failure in the recent for some minutes. I am trying to modify the script so the expect breaks/exits the code if the password is wrong on the first attempt.
echo "Enter the admin password:  "
read password
itmp=$(mktemp)

cat > $itmp << EOF
set timeout 5
spawn ssha -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no admin@$hostname
set timeout 5
expect "password"
send "$password\r"
expect "$hostname"
send "command1\r"
expect "$hostname"
send "command2\r"
expect "$hostname"
send "command3\r"
expect "$hostname"
send "exit\r"
expect eof
EOF
chmod 600 $itmp

expect -f $itmp
rm $itmp


Use IFS= read -r -s password to read the password exactly as the user types it, and to hide it from view.

This expect code does not send the password multiple times. If the password is incorrect and the remote host prompts for the password again, then the expect code will wait 5 seconds to see the hostname, it will time out, and then it will send "command1" which is probably not the right password. Similarly, after each expect
command times out, you'll send "command2" and "command3" and "exit"
You need to handle the "incorrect password" response specifically, and abort the expect script:
expect "password"
send "$password\r"
expect {
  "incorrect password" { # adjust that string as needed
    send_user "You gave me the wrong password\n"
    exit 1
  }
  $hostname
}
send "command1\r"
...

